# Can we get user's YouTube data (history, recommended videos, ...) through YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I'm new to YouTube API. Is it possible to get user's data if he is authenticated into my application using his Google account.

Comment: Retrieving a user's watch history is no longer officially supported, see [change log for September 15, 2016](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-15-2016). To date, no alternative method has been announced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was User Watch History removed in YouTube Data API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58591466/was-user-watch-history-removed-in-youtube-data-api-v3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube Api v2 used to have a feature like this if i remember correctly.   Unforutnatly that API has long since been shut down.

[Activites.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) which just gives a list of video's recommend that the user watch.   There is nothing for History of what videos the user has watched or liked.

**Authenticated:**

If the user is authenticated you can use the home parameter which is used to show the videos that would be recommend to said user by YouTube

> Set this parameter's value to true to retrieve the activity feed that displays on the YouTube home page for the currently authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks,,Do we need user's api key for this? Can you please tell me the steps

Comment: Its a public method so yes you can use an API key but you are still going to have to figure out what channels to show said user.   There is an option called Home which works on authenticated users.    I recommend testing it here  https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.activities.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&home=true&maxResults=25

Comment: What if the user is not authenticated? Is there a way to display recommended channels like on the YouTube home when not logged in yet?