# Was User Watch History removed in YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

If you look at [YouTube V3 Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs) it will say

> YouTube uses playlists to identify special collections of videos for a channel, such as: (...) watch history (...).

Now, if you go to [Channels List API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and make a call for `part=contentDetails&mine=true` it will list your information but `watchHistory` will appear as `HL` and `watchLater` as `WL`.

It makes me wonder, and so far I couldn't find any explicit mention, from Google/YouTube, were those playlists removed from API? IS there any way to actually get that information from an authenticated user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For quite some time I observed the same values you mentioned on various channels. According to the docs, [watch history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory) and [watch later](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchLater) playlists are deprecated.

Comment: Yup! Deprecated indeed... Thanks!